# Make a dynamodb attribute as partition key of one index and as sort key of another index

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

Is that possible to make an attribute as partition key of one index and as sort key of another index?

For example, I have a table named `Events` with attributes `user`, `status`, `created_at`.

Can I create both of below GSIs
GSI `user_status` [`user` as `partition`, `status` as `sort`]
GSI `status_created_at` [`status` as `partition`, `created_at` as `sort`]

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much the idea with GSIs. In short: the answer is yes.

Be cautious, though, of creating GSIs where you have massive cardinality on a small set of partition keys, such as the second GSI example where you partition on status. Presumably there are only a handful of status values in total but for each status, the cardinality (number of items with the same status) might be very large. The reason this can be a problem is that GSIs, like tables, are subject to read and write capacity limits which apply per partition. As your table scales, having low distribution accross partitions with very high cardinality could result in poor performance.